# Is it normal for Caller ID to display 'Unknown' for some outgoing calls?

Tags: php, twilio

I'm using the [Twilio PHP Library](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php), and placing calls like this:

```
$call = $client->account->calls->create(
    '+15555555555', // I'm using my actual Twilio number
    $number, // The number being called
    'http://fqdn/mytwiml', // Execute this TwiML when call connects
    array('IfMachine' => 'Continue') // Machines are people too
);
```

Calls will intermittently display the Twilio number or 'Unknown' in caller ID. It almost alternates evenly between the two...
Is this normal?

Comment: You should send the details (the numbers you're using, etc) to help@twilio.com and they can help track it down.

Comment: Hi James, You should contact our support team at help@twilio.com - they would be glad to help you work through this problem. - Kevin

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do as stated above in the comments is to contact [Twilio support](https://twilio.com/help/contact).

Sending code samples and [Call Sids](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call#instance-uri) for context is a good idea too!